# Permission problem of adding orderer node to channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I want to add a raft node, because this node belongs to a different organization and needs to submit channel updates to the channel.

```
    export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/config
    configtxgen -printOrg Orderer2Org > ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer2.xiaoyin.com/orderer2.json
    configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config >"config.json"
    jq -s '.[0] * {"channel_group":{"groups":{"Orderer":{"groups": {"Orderer2Org":.[1]}}}}}' config.json ./organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer2.xiaoyin.com/orderer2.json > modified_config.json
    configtxlator proto_encode --input "config.json" --type common.Config >original_config.pb
    configtxlator proto_encode --input "modified_config.json" --type common.Config >modified_config.pb
    configtxlator compute_update --channel_id "xiaochannel" --original original_config.pb --updated modified_config.pb >config_update.pb
    configtxlator proto_decode --input config_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate >config_update.json
    echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"'xiaochannel'", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat config_update.json)'}}}' | jq . >config_update_in_envelope.json
    configtxlator proto_encode --input config_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope >"orderer2_update_in_envelope.pb"
```

When I use the command "peer channel signconfigtx -f "orderer2_update_in_envelope.pb" at Orderer1 node,an error occurs .

```
2021-04-25 15:33:15.408 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 120 streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.56.3:48256 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=3.814211ms
2021-04-25 15:40:53.375 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] ProcessMessage -> WARN 121 [channel: xiaochannel] Rejecting broadcast of config message from 192.168.56.3:48258 because of error: error applying config update to existing channel 'xiaochannel': error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Group]  /Channel/Orderer not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 0 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 1 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied
```

How to configure this command?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

```
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Orderer1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE="/home/network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer1.xiaoyin.com/orderers/osn1.orderer1.xiaoyin.com/tls/ca.crt"
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/home/network/organizations/ordererOrganizations/orderer1.xiaoyin.com/users/Admin@xiaoyin.com/
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7050
peer channel signconfigtx -f "orderer2_update_in_envelope.pb"
peer channel update -o osn1.orderer1.xiaoyin.com:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride osn1.orderer1.xiaoyin.com -c xiaochannel -f orderer2_update_in_envelope.pb  --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA"
```

This solves the problem of permissions.